# Codefirst degrades over time

Tags: c#, sql-server, code-first

The program below is a socket program that receives data at a pretty fast pace. It runs fine with the CodeFirst section disabled. If I enable it, the program starts out fine but then  degrades slowly to the point where nothing appears to be written to the SQL EXPRESS 2012 db. I check this by running the SQL statement below which just selects the last five rows n SQL Management Studio 2012.

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

```
select * from [MarketDataEntities]
where MarketDataEntities.MarketDataEntityID not in (
    select top (
        (select count(*) from [MarketDataEntities]) - 5
    ) MarketDataEntities.MarketDataEntityID
    from  [MarketDataEntities]
)



               using (var dbTDC = new TickDataTestContext())
                {
                    var tde = new SymbolTickDataEntity { Symbol = symbol };
                    if (!dbTDC.SymbolTickDataDbSet.Any(a => a.Symbol.Equals(symbol)))
                    {
                        dbTDC.SymbolTickDataDbSet.Add(tde);
                        dbTDC.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    var mdde = new MarketDataDepthEntity();
                    dbTDC.MarketDataDepthDbSet.Add(mdde);

                    dbTDC.SaveChanges();

                    while (true)
                    {
                        //  Wait for next request from client 
                        int len = socket.Receive(zmq_buffer);
                        if (len < 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Len < 1");

                            continue;
                        }

                        //Console.WriteLine("Got quote");

                        count++;

                        // Copy the bytes
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(zmq_buffer, 0, bytes, 0, len);

                        MarketDataDepth mdd = MarketDataDepth.CreateBuilder().MergeFrom(bytes).Build();

                        PrintMarketDataDepth(mdd);
#if false
                        for (int i = 0; i < mdd.MdCount; i++)
                        {
                            MarketData md = mdd.MdList[i];

                            string timestamp = md.Time;
                            int index = timestamp.IndexOf(",");
                            if(-1 != index)
                                timestamp = timestamp.Remove(index);

                            DateTime parseResult;
                            if (false == System.DateTime.TryParseExact(timestamp, format, provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out parseResult))
                                continue;

                            var mde = new MarketDataEntity
                            {
                                NMDDTag = (long)mdd.NMDDTag,
                                QType = (0 == md.QuoteType ? QuoteType.Bid : QuoteType.Ask),
                                QPrice = md.Price,
                                QSize = md.Size,
                                QSource = md.Source,
                                QLiquidityTag = md.ID,
                                QSilo = md.Silo,
                                QTimeStamp = parseResult
                            };

                            dbTDC.MarketDataDbSet.Add(mde);

                            mdde.Depth.Add(mde);
                        }

                        if (0 == count % 500)
                            dbTDC.SaveChanges();
#endif
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }

                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    public enum QuoteType { Bid = 0, Ask }

    public class MarketDataEntity
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int MarketDataEntityID { get; set; }

        public long NMDDTag { get; set; }
        public QuoteType QType { get; set; }
        public double QPrice { get; set; }
        public double QSize { get; set; }
        public string QSource { get; set; }
        public string QLiquidityTag { get; set; }
        public string QSilo { get; set;}
        [Column("timestamp", TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime QTimeStamp { get; set; }
    }

    public class MarketDataDepthEntity
    {
        public int MarketDataDepthEntityID { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<MarketDataEntity> Depth { get; set; }

        [Column("timestamp", TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public MarketDataDepthEntity() { Depth = new List<MarketDataEntity>(); }
    }

    public class SymbolTickDataEntity
    {
        public int SymbolTickDataEntityID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Required]
        public string Symbol { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<MarketDataDepthEntity> Mdds { get; set; }
        public SymbolTickDataEntity() { Mdds = new List<MarketDataDepthEntity>(); }
    }

    public class TickDataTestContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MarketDataEntity> MarketDataDbSet { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MarketDataDepthEntity> MarketDataDepthDbSet { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SymbolTickDataEntity> SymbolTickDataDbSet { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: How much data are you adding to the DB?  How many rows approximately and over what time period?

Comment: Well right now it is top of book. It is something like 2,000,000 rows per symbol per day. So sometihng like 50,000,000 rows a day? But it degrades within about ten minutes of writting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code  looks like you are keeping around the TickDataTestContext for the lifetime of your application. So as you keep adding data the local cache keeps increasing increasing memory usage hence performance degradation.

You should rewrite the code to create a new instance of TickDataTestContext for each request that needs to be saved then do the work, save changes and dispose the context.